# O evento addEventListener não é escutado

Tags: javascript

Não sei se isso pode interferir ou não, mas eu tenho 3 formulários iguais na mesma página e outros 2 scripts sendo chamados da mesma forma (com `window.addEventListener`)

### HTML

```
<script src="../../js/mail.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/formCurso.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/whatsapp.js"></script>

<form method="POST">

  <label>Nome</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome">

  <label>E-mail</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">

  <label>Telefone/Celular</label>
  <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Telefone/Celular">

  <input type="hidden" value="Colorimetria" name="course" id="course">

  <input type="hidden" value="" name="module" id="module">

  <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light cta btn-large btn-solicitar-modal pulse-hover" id="buttonPress">
   Solicitar curso
  </button>

</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    var regexCharactere = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
    var regexEmail = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
    var regexTel = /(?:^\([0]?[1-9]{2}\)|^[0]?[1-9]{2}[\.-\s]?)[9]?[1-9]\d{3}[\.-\s]?\d{4}$/;
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    var buttonPress = document.getElementById('buttonPress');

    /*A próxima linha não escuta o evento a ser chamado, ignorando todo o resto do código*/

    buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(!regexCharactere.test(name.value) || name.value == "" || name.value == undefined || name.value == null) {
            alert("Nome não reconhecido");
            name.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if(!regexEmail.test(email.value) || email.value == "" || email.value == undefined || name.value == null) {
            alert("E-mail inválido");
            email.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if(!regexTel.test(phone.value) || phone.value == "" || phone.value == undefined || phone.value == null) {
            alert("Insira um telefone correto\n(DDD) + num do telefone");
            phone.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });


});
```

Comment: Testei o seu código e o evento é chamado, aparecem 3 alerts quando se clica no botão sem preencher nada, pode esclarecer qual a sua dúvida? Se preencher os campos de forma válida os alerts aparecem na mesma, penso que seja o seu regex que não funcione bem.

Comment: Como? Eu acabei de testa-lo e não deu nenhuma chamada de evento amigo... Você alterou algo?

Comment: Você disse que tem 3 forms iguais na mesma página, mas está usando `document.getElementByid()` para pegar os inputs... ID significa identificador e deve ser único. Se você tem vários elementos com o mesmo ID você deveria considerar usar classes.

Comment: @fernandosavio entendi, obrigado pela dica. Vou segui-lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute e veja que o evento está sendo chamado corretamente.
A diferença do meu código para o seu é que eu não inseri as tags de script iniciais.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    var regexCharactere = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
    var regexEmail = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;
    var regexTel = /(?:^\([0]?[1-9]{2}\)|^[0]?[1-9]{2}[\.-\s]?)[9]?[1-9]\d{3}[\.-\s]?\d{4}$/;
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    var buttonPress = document.getElementById('buttonPress');

    /*A próxima linha não escuta o evento a ser chamado, ignorando todo o resto do código*/

    buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(!regexCharactere.test(name.value) || name.value == "" || name.value == undefined || name.value == null) {
            alert("Nome não reconhecido");
            name.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if(!regexEmail.test(email.value) || email.value == "" || email.value == undefined || name.value == null) {
            alert("E-mail inválido");
            email.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if(!regexTel.test(phone.value) || phone.value == "" || phone.value == undefined || phone.value == null) {
            alert("Insira um telefone correto\n(DDD) + num do telefone");
            phone.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    });


});
```

```html
<form method="POST">

  <label>Nome</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome">

  <label>E-mail</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">

  <label>Telefone/Celular</label>
  <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Telefone/Celular">

  <input type="hidden" value="Colorimetria" name="course" id="course">

  <input type="hidden" value="" name="module" id="module">

  <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light cta btn-large btn-solicitar-modal pulse-hover" id="buttonPress">
   Solicitar curso
  </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado @MauroAlmeida, por mais que o código esteja errado na forma lógica, estava mais preocupado pq ele não estava chamando... Uma coisa que percebi nas minhas páginas é que tenho versões diferentes de jquerys entre outros arquivos. Talvez seja isso, de acordo com você não alterou uma linha do meu código (só não adicionou a chamada do script).

Answer (score 0):

Insira `e.preventDefault();` logo após abrir o escopo da função. Esse comando evita que a página seja redirecionada pelo método POST do seu form.

```js
buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();   

  // restante do código
})
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Elihofni, mas mesmo assim não está indo. E o intuito da pergunta é o evento que não esta sendo executado...